# What is the significance of annihilator subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I am a mathematics student.I am studying linear algebra in which I have dual spaces,annihilators and other related concepts.I want to know what is the motivation behind defining annihilator of a subspace which is $W^0=\{\phi\in V^*: W\subset \operatorname{Ker}\phi\}$. I have seen the result $\dim W^0=\dim V-\dim W$,but I cannot understand what is the exact correlation between $W$ and its annihilator $W^0$. Can someone give me some motivation behind defining dual spaces and annihilators.One motivation of defining dual basis I think is to consider the transpose,but I am not sure.For annihilators the motivation is I think from orthogonal complement of inner product.I am also confused with the notions $V/W^0\simeq W$ or $(V/W)^*\simeq W^0$.

Comment: That's simple: $W^0$ is the set of linear equations that are satisfied by all elements in $W$.

Comment: $W^0$ can be identified with the orthogonal complement $W^\perp$ of $W$.

Comment: @Berci How?Please elaborate

Comment: @Berci I have $W^\perp=\{y\in V:\langle x,y\rangle=0, \forall x\in W\}$ how does that correspond to $W^0$?

Comment: Via the Riesz representation: in a finite dimensional inner product space every linear functional $\phi:V\to K$ is of the form $\phi(x)=\langle v,x\rangle$ for a unique vector $v$.

Comment: @Bernard $W^0$ for $W\subset \mathbb R^n$ represents hyperplane through the origin and the points of $W$.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar: with the definition of $W^0$ you give, it is a subspace of $V^*$, and it's not  necessarily a hyperplane in $V^*$.

Comment: @Bernard you are right.

Comment: @Bernard What is the geometrical significance of annihilator.

Comment: Fir me, it is implicitly contained in my comment: it is the set of (linear) equations of the hyperplanes containing $V$

Comment: @Berci what is the relation between annihilator subspace and a system of linear equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:**"I have seen the result $dim(W_0)=dim(V)−dim(W)$,but I cannot understand what is the exact correlation between $W$ and its annihilator $W_0$. Can someone give me some motivation behind defining dual spaces and annihilators.One motivation of defining dual basis I think is to consider the transpose,but I am not sure.For annihilators the motivation is I think from orthogonal complement of inner product."

**Answer:** Given a vector subspace $W \subseteq V$ and let $i: W \rightarrow V$ be the inclusion map. You get an exact sequence of $k$-vector spaces

$$0 \rightarrow W \rightarrow V \rightarrow V/W \rightarrow 0$$

and when you dualize this sequence you get an exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow (V/W)^* \rightarrow V^* \rightarrow^{i^*} W^* \rightarrow 0$$

where the map $i^*$ is the induced map: By definition $i^*(\phi):=\phi \circ i$.

From this you may prove that there are equalities $W^0 = ker (i^*) = (V/W)^*$ as subspaces of $V^*$ as follows: If $i^*(\phi):=
\phi \circ i=0$ it follows $\phi(W)=0$ hence $\phi \in W^0$. Conversely if $\phi \in W^0$ it follows $\phi(W)=0$ and hence $\phi \in i^*$.
From this it follows that

$$dim(W^0)=dim((V/W)^*)=dim(V^*)-dim(W^*)=dim(V)-dim(W).$$

You need to know what a quotient vector space is and what the dual vector space is. You do not need an inner product for this to hold.

**Comment:** I am also confused with the notions $V/W^0\simeq W$ or $(V/W)^*\simeq W^0$.

**Note:** Given any inclusion of vector spaces $i: W \rightarrow V$ you may construct the "quotient vector space" $V/W$. The sub space $W \subseteq V$ defines an equivalence relation on the set of vectors $v\in V$: two vectors $u,v$ are equivalent $u \cong v$ iff $u-v \in W$. The set of equivalence classes is denoted $V/W$ and given a vector $v\in V$ we denote by $[v]$ the equivalence class of $v$. This is the class $[v]:=\{v+u: u\in W\}$. The set of equivalence classes $V/W$ is naturally a $k$-vector space and there is a canonical map  $p:V \rightarrow V/W$ of $k$-vector spaces defined by $p(v):=[v]$. It has kernel $ker(p)=W$.

Comment: I don't know category theory,so I did not understand this concept of exact sequences.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar - taking the quotient vector space is a fundamental construction in linear algebra and you should verify that there is a canonical map of $k$-vector spaces $p: V \rightarrow V/W$ with kernel $W$ and where $dim(V/W)=dim(V)-dim(W)$. Moreover $dim(W)=dim(W^*)$ and the formula given in my post answers your question.